# Docker environment variables not pass correctly

Tags: linux, bash, docker, unix

My Docker image (CentOS 7) runs a bash script which expects some environment variables. The bash script is started via the `ENTRYPOINT` directive.

```
# Inside the Dockerfile
ADD run.sh .
RUN chmod 777 run.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "./run.sh"]

# Inside run.sh
echo MakeDir: $MakeDir
```

To start this container, I run the following command:

```
docker run -t myimage -e MakeDir=/path/to/something
```

Unfortunately, the run.sh script cannot see the MakeDir environment variable. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If `run.sh` is executable, then you could simply write `ENTRYPOINT ["./run.sh"]`. If it is not executable, then the `-c` option would be incorrect, and you would need `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "./run.sh"]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arguments after the image are passed to (and in this case, ignored by) the command, not `docker run`. Put `-e` *before* the image.

```
docker run -t -e MakeDir=/path/to/something myimage
```

Comment: It's an easy one to make when you get used to being able to mix arguments and options.

Comment: By the way, I entered a *slightly* different command than you: `docker run -e MakeDir=... -t myimage`.

Comment: Extra arguments aren't ignored: they form the "command" part of the Docker container invocation, they overwrite the `CMD` declaration in the Dockerfile, and they are passed as command-line parameters to the entrypoint script (if any).  As a corollary, it's common to end entrypoint scripts with `exec "$@"` so that they actually run the named command.

Comment: I should have been more explicit: `run.sh`, as written, ignores the arguments that are passed to it by `bash`.